# Adding axhline to each subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Some quick context, I've just finished a data analysis with python course on freecodecamp and am now playing around with jupyter notebooks, pandas and matplotlib. To be honest with you I'm still not confident I know what I'm doing but hey ho.

What I want to do is take a dataframe in pandas create a bar chart with all the different categories and their values as subplots, this I've managed to do with the following code where def_data is my dataframe:

```
def_data.drop(['Age'],axis=1).plot(kind = 'bar', subplots = True, layout= (-1,4), legend = False, figsize = (14,20))
```

Which gave me my output:

Graph output of code:

[image: Graph output of code]

For more context this is the data in my dataframe:

DataFrame Data:

[image: DataFrame Data]

This is great as its what I want but I want to improve it further by adding a line for each of these subplots for the mean.

I've done a bit of googling and can find that what I want is something along the lines of:

```
plt.axhline(y=np.nanmean(def_data))
```

But this doesn't seem to work across the subplots, if I turn the subplots argument to False it adds the line, but I'm assuming because there's multiple axis its not liking it. So from what I can gather I need to iterate through each subplot maybe and add the line then, but I'm not sure how I go about iterating through the subplots? This is where I'm now looking for help.

I've tried to add in the `axhline` code after line of code to generate the graph (like below code), I am assuming this didn't work as it's assuming there'd be 1 axis.

```
def_data.drop(['Age'],axis=1).plot(kind = 'bar', subplots = False, layout= (-1,4), legend = False, figsize = (14,20),ax=ax)

ax.axhline(y=np.nanmean(def_data))
```

When calculating the mean as well I've tried `def_data.mean()` and this gives an error about true values, some further googling got me to importing `numpy` and using `np.nanmean` instead. This works on a singular axis graph but doesn't seem to for subplots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot mean in subplots - Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67325888/plot-mean-in-subplots-seaborn)

Comment: You do `axs = def_data....plot(...subplots=True)` and then you can use `for ax, col in zip(axs.flat, [c for c in def_data.columns if c != 'Age']):   ax.axhline(np.nanmean(def_data[col]))`.

Comment: To share your dataframe you can use the output of `def_data.to_dict('list')`. A screenshot is quite annoying as it doesn't allow people to easily experiment with your data.  If your data is very long, just use a subset.  If your data is private, please create something similar with test data.